# Example request: equivariant formality versus formality for homogeneous spaces

Tags: equivariant-cohomology, rational-homotopy-theory

Recall that a continuous action of a compact Lie group $T$ on a space $X$ is said to be *equivariantly formal* if the Borel equivariant cohomology $H^*(X \times_T ET;\mathbb Q)$ surjects through restriction onto the singular cohomology $H^*(X;\mathbb Q)$. The action $T \times X \to X$ induces by pullback maps 
$$C^*(X) \to C^*(T) \otimes C^*(X),$$ 
$$H^*(X) \to H^*(T) \otimes H^*(X),$$
and following with the evaluation pairing $C_*(T) \otimes C^*(T) \to \mathbb Q$, one can consider both $C^*(X)$ and $H^*(X)$ as differential graded $H_*(T)$-modules in the sense that multiplication by an element of $H^*(T)$ commutes up to sign with the differential of the complex. (If one replaces $T$ with another compact, connected Lie group, one obtains analogous statements involving weak module structures.)

In the paper where they call the notion of equivariant formality to attention, Goresky, Kottwitz, and MacPherson, assuming real coefficients throughout, prove such an action is equivariant formal if and only if both

- the cohomology of the action $T \times X \to X$ is trivial in that it factors as $$H^*(X) \overset\sim\to H^0(T) \otimes H^*(X) \hookrightarrow H^*(T) \otimes H^*(X),$$
- the complexes $(C^*(X),\delta)$ and $(H^*(X),0)$ can be connected through a zig-zag of quasi-isomorphisms of ***differential graded $H_*(T)$-modules***—not assumed to behave well with respect to multiplication.

This is analogous to the notion of *formality*, due to Sullivan, which asks that the DGAs $(C^*(X),\delta)$ and $(H^*(X),0)$ be connected through a zig-zag of ***algebra*** quasi-isomorphisms.

In the specific case I'm interested in now, $X$ is a homogeneous space $G/T$ for $G$ a compact Lie group containing $T$ as a *nonmaximal* torus, and the $T$-action is the natural $t\cdot gT := (tg)T$. In this setting, in every example I know of where the action is equivariantly formal, the space $G/T$ is also formal, even though there seems not to be an *a priori* connection between these different categories of quasi-isomorphism.

**Does anyone know have a reference to (or otherwise know of) an example where the action $T \times G/T \to G/T$ is equivariantly formal but $G/T$ is *not* formal?**

Comment: In the first sentence, are you pulling back along the map $x \mapsto (x,*) $?

Comment: I prefer to denote the elements of the homotopy quotient as $[x,e]$ or $(x,e)\cdot T$, but yes, it's this map.